# Delete a message without ctx attribute

Tags: python, discord.py

### The Problem

I am running a bot event on a cog and I want to delete a message if it is not in the right channel. However, on_message only seems to take the messages argument so I cannot delete the message sent in context:

````
 @commands.Cog.listener()
async def on_message(self, message):
    musicchannel = self.bot.get_channel(705116959804489898)
    if message.content.startswith('-p'):
        if message.channel.id == musicchannel.id:
            pass
        else:
            await message.channel.send("```ini\n[Music commands only in the appropriate channel]```", delete_aft$
            await asyncio.sleep(4)
            message.delete()
````

Usually you would have the ctx argument so it's as simple as `ctx.message.delete()` but that will not work in this case.

### What I've tried

I have attempted to fetch the message with `self.bot.fetch_message(message.id)` but bot does not take the attribute fetch_message().

### Solution

Somehow I didn't notice it straight away but all you need is `await` as `.delete()` is a co-routine.

Answer (score 1):

All you're missing is `await`. As `delete()` is a co-routine, you just need to modify the event so that:

```py
@commands.Cog.listener()
async def on_message(self, message):
    musicchannel = self.bot.get_channel(705116959804489898)
    if message.content.startswith('-p'):
        if message.channel.id == musicchannel.id:
            pass
        else:
            #code
            await message.delete()
```

---

**References:**

- [`Message.delete()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Guild.delete)

Comment: I can't believe I didn't see that

Comment: @ChonkyWonky Haha it's fine, everyone misses an `await` here and there :^)